# MySQL update md5 of another column

Tags: mysql, sql, hash, md5

I need to do an update query making an md5 hash from my google calendar column.  This is my query:

```
UPDATE `ea_appointments` SET `hash` = MD5(`id_google_calendar`)
```

Would this work to make something like this?:

```
Table: ea_appointments
id_google_calendar                             Hash
e5e3were760lkj792c7t5vm61bvk_20160729T200000Z  d5f9f4ef02e438d49c8bf39cd4b4118d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it'll be work.
And you can loosely check it by:

```
select md5('test');
```

Result:

```
+----------------------------------+
| md5('test')                      |
+----------------------------------+
| 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 |
+----------------------------------+
```

Or:

```
select md5('e5e3were760lkj792c7t5vm61bvk_20160729T200000Z');
```

Result:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| md5('e5e3were760lkj792c7t5vm61bvk_20160729T200000Z') |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| 06b5a13d9a7b0ed26ab1406434954972                     |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Or:

```
create table t(id_google_calendar varchar(100), hash varchar(100));
insert into t values ('e5e3were760lkj792c7t5vm61bvk_20160729T200000Z', '');
update t set Hash = md5(id_google_calendar);
select * from t;
```

Result:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| id_google_calendar                            | hash                             |
+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| e5e3were760lkj792c7t5vm61bvk_20160729T200000Z | 06b5a13d9a7b0ed26ab1406434954972 |
+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would work.

Also I suggest that you test it first.
You can test query with:

- Select statement: 
  SELECT id_google_calendar, MD5(id_google_calendar) as hash  FROM ea_appointments
- Update record in test table. Create some test table add few record in it and run query